# Perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, forwarding, decltype

If we have the following:

```
template <class T>
struct B{
  T data;
}

struct A{
  int data_array[100];
}

int main()
{
  A x;
  const A x_const;

  auto y1 = f(A());
  auto y2 = f(x);
  auto y3 = f(x_const);
  auto y4 = f(std::move(x));
}
```

I want to know an `f` (preferably function, but macro is okay also) such that:

```
decltype(y1) == B<A>
decltype(y2) == B<A&>
decltype(y3) == B<const A&>
decltype(y4) == B<A&&>
```

That is, `f` perfectly forwards `x` into an object of `B`.

Comment: [What for?](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)

Comment: You can choose function overloading as the last resort. :)

Answer (score 8):

This is impossible. For `y1` and `y4`, then they both take rvalues of type A, but you want them to return different types. How should `f` know what to return?

Comment: Well, `decltype(A())` is `A` but `decltype(std::move(A()))` is `A&&`, so there is some difference.

Comment: @HighCommander4: They're both rvalues. There's no reference or other language construct that can discriminate between A and an unnamed A&&- indeed, it's half the point that you can't.

Comment: @HighCommander4 The difference in question is that one is a prvalue and the other is an xvalue. Since argument passing allows discriminating between lvalues and rvalues only, it is indeed impossible to detect the difference inside a function (and this is by design).

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename T>
auto f(T&& t) -> B<decltype(std::forward<T>(t))>
{
    return B<decltype(std::forward<T>(t))>{std::forward<T>(t)};
}
```

This does **almost** what you want. The only difference is for the first one the type is `B<A&&>` rather than `B<A>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
auto y1 = f(A());
auto y4 = f(std::move(x));
```

Will not be distinguishable, as `A()` produce a temporary which will bind to `A&&`.